# Migrate a Spring 3.1 Java project from Eclipse to Netbeans

Tags: spring, netbeans

I am migrating a Spring Java Project (using Oracle DB) from Eclipse to Netbeans. It was almost easy but I did not succeed in acessing to the DB (the application was using spring security for logging). The logon was unsuccessful (Access denied). I suppose that in the Netbeans version the Oracle Db was not accessed. I left  the context.xml file in the same META-INF directory, with the same name and the same content, than that of the Eclipse version. Is this right ? Why the access is denied in the Netbeans version ?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8 in Netbeans and Tomcat 7 in Eclipse.

Comment: This is one of the reasons for using a build tool like Maven or Gradle. You make your setup independent of the ide

Comment: Unfortunately , I don't know maven

Comment: Making a project based on the layout/support in an IDE is a very bad idea. Use something like maven, ant or gradle to build your project and manage your dependencies. So instead of moving from Eclipse to Netbeans I would strongly suggest you move from Eclipse to, say Maven, and make your project independent of the IDE.

Comment: @rolando the basics are easy enough to learn. you can get started in an hour or two, it's worth it